# Error in Xamarin's HelloWorld

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created new Android Application in Xamarin and it when I launch it, it should start a simple hello world app on my phone. (The connection works, since I am able to develop apps on ADT in Eclipse). But when I launch it in Xamarin, I get this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(5,5):
>
> Error XA0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com.
>
> Reason: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:
>
> Directory 'C:\Users\VilĂ©m\Documents\Projects\HelloWorld3\HelloWorld3\bin\Debug' not found. (XA0000) (HelloWorld3)

I have checked and the HelloWorld3\bin directory doesn't exist. Why it doesn't exist? I had a clean installation of Xamarin starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Xamarin doesn't fully support full Unicode names (my username is Vilém) and it created another folder called VilĂ©m and that was empty. Creating new user profile fixed the problem.

Comment: yes, this is true. I had so many pain with it and russian name, i just moved all my projects to C:\Projects

Comment: I have chosen C:\Projects as well :)